# Ghost - Can't connect to the bootstrap socket (localhost 8000) ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, linux, ghost-blog

I have been trying for a long time to debug my ghost blog as you can see [here](https://forum.ghost.org/t/ghost-blog-running-but-i-get-http-error-502-when-trying-to-load-it-i-believe-it-is-related-with-ownership-of-content-dir/9222/3).

I have made some progress the problem seems to be related to an error on the bootstrap socket of ghost.

My `config.production.json` in my Digital Ocean server is:

```
{
  "url": "https://www.mifitnessfacil.com",
  "server": {
    "port": 2369,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "root",
      "password": "foobar",
      "database": "foobar"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/ghost/content"
  },
  "bootstrap-socket": {
    "port": 8000,
    "host": "localhost"
  }
}
```

When running `ghost run` I get:

```
[2019-10-03 14:24:00] INFO Ghost is running in production...
[2019-10-03 14:24:00] INFO Your site is now available on https://www.mifitnessfacil.com/
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] INFO Ctrl+C to shut down
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Can't connect to the bootstrap socket (localhost 8000) ECONNREFUSED
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Tries: 0
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Retrying...
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Can't connect to the bootstrap socket (localhost 8000) ECONNREFUSED
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Tries: 1
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Retrying...
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Can't connect to the bootstrap socket (localhost 8000) ECONNREFUSED
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Tries: 2
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Retrying...
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] WARN Can't connect to the bootstrap socket (localhost 8000) ECONNREFUSED
[2019-10-03 14:24:01] INFO Ghost boot 3.299s
```

### Update

- Its running on `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`
- Node version 10.16.3
- Npm version 6.9.0

#### Answer

Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58274370/4031815

Comment: @CommonSenceCode What version of Node are you using? If you are using an older version of Node, update, then ghost update --force

Comment: @tim thanks for trying I update from node 8 to latest stable node 10.16.3 and I still get the same bug `Can't connect to the bootstrap socket (localhost 8000)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

removing `bootstrap-socket` from the `config.production.json` solved that issue yet I still get `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`when visiting my website.

### Update 2 and solution:

https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost-CLI/issues/1017

Comment: Were there any issues removing bootstrap-socket?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `bootstrap-socket` from your `config.production.json` and restart, most probably port 8000 is already inuse or bootstap is unable to make a connection there.
In essence reflect this in your `config.production.json`:

```
{
  "url": "https://www.mifitnessfacil.com",
  "server": {
    "port": 2369,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "root",
      "password": "foobar",
      "database": "foobar"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/ghost/content"
  }
}
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Worked for me! Do I need the bootstrap socket for anything though? A bit worried to have removed it...

Answer (score 1):

this is my first "Answer" here. I ran into this problem during a new install, and had nothing to loose. To fix the error I purged both the Mysql-server and Node.js (apt purge, as root) with wildcard * at the end of mysql. I also removed all associated folders for Mysql in /etc and /usr/share. As for associated folders for Nodejs, I just removed the ones from /etc.

I also uninstalled Ghost. Made a new site directory and re-installed Node.js, Mysql, & Ghost. I let Ghost take care of the SSL. I chose to just start Ghost at the conclusion of setup vs run (debug). And it was working!

I think I caused this problem by installing Certbot which configured SSL certs. Then when I installed Ghost, acme.sh was also installed. I think the double SSL solutions affected more then the obvious.

The solution I randomly got from Google worked. Search "uninstall or completely remove mysql ubuntu 16.04" (even though I'm running 20.04) Instructions from [linuxscriptshub](https://linuxscriptshub.com/uninstall-completely-remove-mysql-ubuntu-16-04/) I think putting the wildcard symbol helped a lot.

As for removing all the directories, that was my idea because it seemed to make sense to remove all config and support files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30582760)

Answer (score 0):

Please run

```sh
sudo netstat -lnp | grep 8000
```

and see if port 8000 is already in use. If it is then change the port on ghost config or disable the process that is using the port.

Comment: That command isn't printing anything. Anyways I tried I `sudo ps aux | grep 8000`and get `ghost-m+ 32461  0.0  0.1  14856  1148 pts/0`whenn I try killing it: `sudo kill -9 32461` I get "No such process"